# Android: Dynamically add two custom checkboxes in a same line

Tags: android

What should I do to use custom checkboxes if I add my checkboxes dynamically in my code? (On the java code not on the XML files.) . Like I want to add two checkbox in a single line in linear layout based on the response from server dynamically. ![This image explain my requirement][1].
[1] :https://stackoverflow.com/66778d9f-ae68-408a-a0f9-bc0af3e99c7a

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of your Linear Layout Id. Just assign id to your Linear Layout and use the following code:

```
        LinearLayout ll= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox(this);
        CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox(this);
        ll.addView(cb1);
        ll.addView(cb2);
```

You can also use `ll.addview(Context, LayoutParams)` . For this, you have to configure LayoutParams . It contains the values like `wrap_content, match_parent, gravity` etc.